# Nodejs nested native module install

Tags: node.js, module, installation, npm, node-gyp

I have a web app that simplified structure looks like this.

```
.
├── app.js
├── native_modules
│   └── my_module_addon
│       ├── binding.gyp
│       ├── index.js
│       ├── node_modules
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── my_module_addon.cc
├── node_modules
├── package.json
```

I have developed native module addon and linked it.
I'd like to install easily my native addon after fetching the project from repo just calling npm and then automatically calling node-gyp rebuild.

```
npm install
```

Well, my app package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyWebApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "my_module_addon": "file:./native_modules/my_module_addon"
  }
}
```

And my module package.json:

```
{
  "name": "scs3reader_addon",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Awesome Addon",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "install": "node-gyp rebuild"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bindings": "^1.2.1",
    "nan": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "gypfile": true
}
```

To link my native addon I add it to dependencies

```
"my_module_addon": "file:./native_modules/my_module_addon"
```

The problem appears when I call npm install on web app I have all my modules installed and node-gyp executed but have no idea why there is no build folder and output files for native addon.

```
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/my_module_addon/my_module_addon.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/my_module_addon.node
my_module_addon@1.0.0 node_modules/my_module_addon
├── bindings@1.2.1
└── nan@2.2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have git repo for native module? If you do - try this dependency style

```
"my_module_addon": "git+ssh://admin@mydomain.com/~/repos/my_module_addon"
```

That should work properly with `npm install`